# How to use setIcon() in a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, imageicon

How do you use the JFrame.setIcon() method with a .ico file?
I'm using and ImageIcon as an argument. The compile error:

```
CodeBlocksMain.java:33: error: cannot find symbol
        setIcon (icon);
        ^
  symbol:   method setIcon(ImageIcon)
  location: class CodeBlocksMain
1 error
```

Comment: You need a little more information as we can't see the line with the error in context. I do like that you showed the error line.

Comment: there is no `setIcon` in JFame , Try this: `setIconImage(new ImageIcon("///your image path").getImage());`

Answer (score 5):

`setIcon` is undefined for `JFrame`. You're looking for [JFrame#setIconImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setIconImage%28java.awt.Image%29)

Comment: Thank you, that is what I was looking for, I know to ask you in the future.